# Ubuntu server glusterfs and virt-manager

Tags: virtualization, cluster, virt-manager

Trying to install glusterfs on 3 Ubuntu 18.04 servers.
Everything works if i add it to fstab and mount the volume.
No problem, read, write, delete. And it updates on the server.

If i add it to virt-manager, i can see the files, and delete existing images, but not create new ones.

if i try qemu-img, i get:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 gluster://gluster3/gv0/vm1.img 10G
qemu-img: gluster://gluster3/gv0/vm1.img: Unknown protocol 'gluster'
```

So close, but yet so far.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the EXACT same problem.
I **think** the problem is qemu wasn't compiled with GlusterFS support (from the build log):

> ../configure --with-pkgversion="Debian 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.9" --extra-cflags="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<>/qemu-2.11+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DCONFIG_QEMU_DATAPATH='\"/usr/share/qemu:/usr/share/seabios:/usr/lib/ipxe/qemu\"' -DVENDOR_UBUNTU" --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed" --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=/usr/lib/qemu --localstatedir=/var --disable-blobs --disable-strip --interp-prefix=/etc/qemu-binfmt/%M --localstatedir=/var  --disable-user \
>       --enable-system \
>       --enable-linux-user \
>       --enable-modules \
>       --enable-linux-aio --audio-drv-list=pa,alsa,oss --enable-attr --enable-bluez --enable-brlapi --enable-virtfs --enable-cap-ng --enable-curl --enable-fdt --enable-gnutls --disable-gtk --disable-vte --enable-libiscsi --enable-curses --enable-smartcard --enable-rbd --enable-rdma --enable-vnc-sasl --enable-seccomp --enable-spice --enable-libusb --enable-usb-redir --enable-xen --enable-xfsctl --enable-vnc --enable-vnc-jpeg --enable-vnc-png --enable-kvm --enable-vhost-net \

Which further reinforced by looking further down the log:

> **GlusterFS support no**

(Full log here: [qemu build log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/399539484/buildlog_ubuntu-bionic-amd64.qemu_1%3A2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.9_BUILDING.txt.gz))

If I'm wrong I'd be very happy to know about it.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into it, and get back to you :)

Comment: That answer is absolutely correct and the reason can be found in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glusterfs/+bug/1274247